# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(2n)!} = \frac{1}{2}e^{1/4} \sqrt{\pi} \text{erf}(\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, error-function

I would like to prove:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(2n)!} = \frac{1}{2}e^{1/4} \sqrt{\pi} \text{erf}(\frac{1}{2})$$

What I did was consider:

$$e^{-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n}}{n!}$$

Then integrate term by term from $0$ to $x$ to get:

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erf} (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$$

Then I substituted in $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and tried some manipulations but didn't get anywhere. May someone help, thanks.

Comment: Well, one thing that would algebraically simplify your life slightly would be to observe that it is the same to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n)!} = e^{1/4} \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}(1/2)/2$.

Comment: I used that idea when manipulating but did not get anywhere. I don't see where the $e^{1/4}$ or the $(2n)!$ would  come from using my approach @Ian .

Comment: It might help to know the more general expression: $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{n! x^n}{(2 n)!}=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{x/4} \sqrt{x} \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)$$ Or alternatively $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{n! x^{2n}}{(2 n)!}=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2/4} x ~\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: I tried to use the Taylor series on that more general expression, and got the coefficients to be undefined. @You'reInMyEye

Comment: Actually if I evaluate the limit as $x \to 0$ of the first two derivatives I get what I want @You'reInMyEye. Do you now how can I show the coefficients of $x^n$ will be want for all $x^n$ ?

Comment: See also: [Sum: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n)!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2354004)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $\frac{n!}{(2n)!}=\frac{B(n,n+1)}{(n-1)!}$, hence:

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n!}{(2n)!} = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{n-1}(1-x)^n}{(n-1)!}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)e^{x(1-x)}\,dx$$
and the result follows by setting $x=t+\frac{1}{2}$ in the last integral, leading to $e^{1/4}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-u^2}\,du.$

Comment: Thanks. May I ask, how did you knew to consider $B(n,n+1)$?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: because $$\frac{n!}{(2n)!}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}=\frac{B(n,n+1)}{(n-1)!}.$$